# Fetch data from wordpress DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have 2 meta keys which i want attached to particular post type in a single instance, and i created the sql query

```
  SELECT DISTINCT p.ID, p.post_title, pmo.meta_value, pmj.meta_value
  FROM wp_posts AS p
  RIGHT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pmo ON p.ID = pmo.post_id
  RIGHT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pmj ON p.ID = pmj.post_id
  WHERE (pmo.meta_key = '_order_meta' AND pmj.meta_key = '_order_jobs')
  AND p.post_type = '_order'
  AND p.post_status = 'publish'
  ORDER BY p.ID DESC LIMIT 10
```

But when i var dump the data.

it only shows the last 'meta_value', although i am fetching 2 meta_vales

Comment: They need to have unique names. Use the `AS` keyword to give each meta_value column a distinct name, like `pmo.meta_value AS pmo_meta_value, pmj.meta_value AS pmj_meta_value`

Comment: okay, but the query will be look like .. ,,

Comment: thank you, i get your point. its fixed now.